# Why won't Eclipse recognize $PERL5LIB?

Tags: eclipse, perl, bioperl

I followed [BioPerl manual](http://www.bioperl.org/wiki/Using_Git): I cloned a fresh copy of `bioperl-live` under `~/src` then added the following line to my `~/.profile` (I'm using Ubuntu):

```
export PERL5LIB="$HOME/src/bioperl-live:$PERL5LIB"
```

However,BioPerl modules are not recognized in Eclipse, e.g.:

```
Can't locate Bio/Tools/GFF.pm in @INC (@INC contains: 
 /home/dave/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.epic.debug 
 /home/dave/workspace_workspace/mars/scripts/lib 
 /etc/perl 
 /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1 
 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1 
 /usr/lib/perl5 
 /usr/share/perl5 
 /usr/lib/perl/5.10 
 /usr/share/perl/5.10 
 /usr/local/lib/site_perl )
```

What do I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~/.profile` is read when you log in. To use that setting until the next time you log in, start a terminal, run the `export PERL5LIB=…` line, then start Eclipse or any other BioPerl-using program from that terminal.